# Error deploy App Laravel 5 en Heroku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku

Al ejecutar el comando `$git push heroku master` me tira el siguiente error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found
```

Segui todos los pasos de instalación de la librería https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator y no tengo problemas de forma local.

Aqui esta mi composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "dev-l5",
    "way/generators": "dev-feature/laravel-five-stable",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "v2.5.4"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"repositories": {
    "repo-name": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:jamisonvalenta/Laravel-4-Generators.git"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es porque tienes el paquete en *require-dev*, agregalo en *require* y listo. Por defecto Heroku hace el *deploy* en modo producción y composer no va instalar ningún paquete de *require-dev*

Hay que recordar que lo que agregamos en *require-dev* son paquetes que no son necesarios para que el proyecto funcione, pero si para su desarrollo, por lo tanto no deberían ser incluidos en la versión de producción del proyecto.

Como nota final, puedes checar los logs de tus *deployments* en Heroku en: overview/view build log y te mostrará todos los paquetes que fueron instalados